# (Google Embed API) How to change chart-table-style width

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, google-api-java-client, graph-visualization

(**This is regarding google-embed-api** NOT google charts, Stack Overflow won't let me create a new tag without 1500 reputation)

Hello,

I'm not incredible at CSS, and am working on a project where I must present a bunch of columns per dimension using googles new charts embed API. The chart is created through a js call to gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart() which creates what I want, perfectly, however the CSS settings in the JS call are overriding the one's I specify.

1. Calling gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart()
2. Creates a google charts table, in the div below, with width set to 450px
3. The js created in-div css style overrides my CSS file's width : 100%

Any help would be huge, and thanks!
-Alex

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer JIC anyone else is looking

Rather than try to override the styling in CSS, I found that google charts offers a width argument in the options elements. To set the chart width simply add options and define width in options: `{width: '100%'}`

```js
    chart: {
          type: 'TABLE',
          container: 'sessions_table',
          options: {width: '100%'}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chart: {
      type: 'TABLE',
      container: 'sessions_table',
      options: {width: '100%'}
    }
```

this is only work for Table charts.when it come's for Line charts you have to trigger the chart redraw on window resize.

You can see the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32144255/9074134) answer